# Interacting with two loops

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x

I am new to programming and was trying to solve a problem. What I want is to have two loops simultaneously decreasing.

```
    for i in range(1000,100,-1):
        for j in range(1000,100,-1):
            product=j*k
```

If I'am not wrong, this would give me 1000*1000, 1000*999, 1000*998 and so on. What if I want 1000*1000, 999*999, 998*998 and so on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this case, you should just use one loop:

```
for i in range(1000, 100, -1):
    product = i*i
    ...
```

For the general case of wanting to advance two loop variables simultaneously instead of nesting the loops, you want `zip`:

```
for i, j in zip(some_iterable, some_other_iterable):
    ...
```

Comment: Oops that was a bad example by me. Zip is what I was looking for! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I do not see the point why you should need two loops surely you would do:

```
for i in range(1000,100,-1):
    product=i*i
```

Comment: Damn @user2357112 you got there faster than me :(

Comment: I just tried to take a general example to explain what I meant. Realized later it did not make sense.

Comment: Dont worry we were all beginners at one time although some of us dont want to admit it :)